# Give space to parent window when shrinking windows in emacs

Tags: emacs

In the following scenario in `emacs`, window 3 is the product of calling `split-window-vertically` in window 1.

```
================
Window 1
Line 1
Line 2
================
Window 3
Line 1

================
Window 2
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
================
```

When `fit-window-to-buffer` is called on window 3, window 2 receives the extra space because the resizing occurs on the bottom-edge of window 3, like so:

```
================
Window 1
Line 1
Line 2
================
Window 3
Line 1
================
Window 2
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4

================
```

How can I shrink window 3 to the size of its buffer contents while giving the extra space to its parent, window 1? I want my frame to look like this:

```
================
Window 1
Line 1
Line 2

================
Window 3
Line 1
================
Window 2
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
================
```

For reference, this phenomenon is observable in `magit`. Window 1 is the magit status buffer, window 2 any other buffer and window 3 is a `magit-key-mode-popup` buffer (like the commit menu).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just fyi, you can also hit `C-x -` in Window 3 which calls `shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer`, which calls `fit-window-to-buffer`.  That said, sorry i don't know of a way to make it behave as described.  Simple workaround would be to repeatedly enlarge Window 1 with the following key combos: `C-x ^` then `C-x z` finally as many `z`s as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something that supports directional window movement. `windmove` works nicely (or if you have `evil`, that works too [just replace windmove with evil-window])

```
(defun shift-window-down ()
  "Shift the current window down"
  (interactive)
  (windmove-up)
  (call-interactively 'enlarge-window)
  (windmove-down)
  (windmove-down)
  (call-interactively 'shrink-window)
  (windmove-up))

(defun fit-window-to-buffer-up ()
  "Call fit-window-to-buffer and give extra space to the window above"
  (interactive)
  (let ((old-height (window-total-height)))
    (fit-window-to-buffer)
    (dotimes (temp (- old-height (window-total-height)))
      (shift-window-down))))
```